# Sequelize model querying- Why don't both routes work at same time?

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js

I am playing with some routes in Express, using Sequelize to create my models.
I have two models that both work independently of one another. But I want them both to work at the same time. To someone experienced there is probably an obvious reason.

My first route gets items by primary key:

```
router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const categoryData = await Category.findByPk(req.params.id)
    .then((result) => {
      res.status(200).json(result);
    });

  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err)
  }
});
```

An example result of this query looks like:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "category_name": "Shirts"
}
```

My second route gets results by another parameter, category_name

Here is this route:

```
router.get('/:category_name', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const categoryData = await Category.findAll({
      where: {category_name: req.params.category_name}
    })
    .then((result) => {
      res.status(200).json(result);
    });

  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err)
  }
});
```

and the results look like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "category_name": "Shorts"
  }
]
```

However, I can only use one route at a time. If both routes are turned on, only one or the other works.  Why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server has no way of differentiating between the two variable endpoint paths.

You have one route /:id, and another /:category_name. When testing out these routes, YOU may know which one you are intending to hit, but the server does not.

Consider adding another level to the path, such as /name/:category_name and /id/:id.